# AngularDart: using template input variables in structural directives

Tags: angular-directive, angular-dart

I have learning AngularDart. Everything went well so for. But I am stuck with structural directives : I cannot figure out how to use the template input variables to implement my own structural directive.

I read many times this document: [Structural Directives](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/structural-directives).

And, although the material below refers to AngularJS, I read this questions/documents:

- [Angular 2: How to access Template Input Variables in Structural Directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536864/angular-2-how-to-access-template-input-variables-in-structural-directives)
- [Angular 2 Custom Structural Directive binding using template input variable is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275700/angular-2-custom-structural-directive-binding-using-template-input-variable-is-n)
- [How to use Angular structural directive with multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789702/how-to-use-angular-structural-directive-with-multiple-inputs)
- [Or, how I wrote a customized version of ngFor](http://teropa.info/blog/2016/03/06/writing-an-angular-2-template-directive.html)

It is said that from the *micosyntax declaration* "`let v=value`", Angular creates the template variable "`let-v`". However, I cannot use the name "`let-v`" in a template since "`let-v`" is not a valid name for a variable.

By the way, if you look at the explanation that is given [here](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor) for the directive `ngFor` :

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let i=index; let odd=odd; trackBy: trackByHeroId"
     [class.odd]="odd">
  ({{i}}) {{hero.name}}
</div>

<template ngFor let-hero [ngForOf]="heroes" let-i="index" let-odd="odd"
          [ngForTrackBy]="trackByHeroId">
  <div [class.odd]="odd">({{i}}) {{hero.name}}</div>
</template>
```

You see that, inside the template, the template input variable `i` is called `i` (not `let-i`):

```
<div [class.odd]="odd">({{i}}) {{hero.name}}</div>
```

I tried a *LOT* of things within the Dart code of my structural directive. But nothing works.

I read [the source code for the directive NgFor](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/master/angular/lib/src/common/directives/ng_for.dart). Something potentially interesting here :

```
  viewRef.setLocal('first', identical(i, 0));
  viewRef.setLocal('last', identical(i, len - 1));
  viewRef.setLocal('index', i);
  viewRef.setLocal('count', len);
```

However, I tried that with no success.

Here is the simple code I wrote:

File: `lib/src/directive_my_dummy.dart`

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Directive(
    selector: '[myDummy]'
)

class MyDummyDirective implements OnInit {
  TemplateRef _templateRef;
  ViewContainerRef _viewContainer;

  MyDummyDirective(TemplateRef templateRef, ViewContainerRef viewContainer) {
    _templateRef = templateRef;
    _viewContainer = viewContainer;
  }

  @Input('let-d')
  List<int> d;

  void ngOnInit() {
    print("One instance of MyDummyDirective is instantiated.");
    EmbeddedViewRef vr = _viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(_templateRef);
    vr.setLocal('d', [1,2,3]);
    print(d.toString());
  }
}
```

File: `lib/app_component.html`

```
<div *myDummy="let d=data">
    This is a dummy test. {{d.toString()}}
</div>

<div *myDummy="let d=[1,2,3]">
    This is a dummy test. {{d.toString()}}
</div>

<div *myDummy="let d=getData()">
</div>

<div *myDummy="let d=[1,2,3]; let name='Toto'"></div>
```

The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/denis-beurive/angulardart-playground/tree/master/directive-structural).

Can you show me a basic example that illustrates the use of the template input variables ?

Answer (score 0):

First, there are two entities that we call "template":

- The component template.
- The (structural) directive template.

The term "*input template variable*" makes reference to the (structural) directive template.

I think that it would be better to use the appellation "*input directive template variable*".

I'll use the appellation "*input directive template variable*" instead of "input template variable".

The role of an *input directive template variable* is to configure a (structural) *directive template*.

Where does the value of an *input directive template variable* come from ?

The answer is: the value of an *input directive template variable* gets assigned within the directive instance. You cannot define the value of an *input directive template variable* directly within the component template. For example, the code `<div *myDummy="let d=10">` below will **NOT** assign the value 10 to the variable `d`.

The value of the *input directive template variable* is assigned from within the directive instance. For example:

```
TemplateRef _templateRef;
ViewContainerRef _viewContainer;
// ...
_viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(_templateRef);
_viewContainer.get(0).setLocal('data', 'MyDummyDirective.data');
```

And you write, within the component template:

```
<div *myDummy="let d=data">
```

I give a simple example:

[lib/src/directive_my_dummy.dart](https://github.com/denis-beurive/angulardart-playground/blob/master/directive-structural/lib/src/directive_my_dummy.dart)

```
@Directive(
    selector: '[myDummy]'
)
class MyDummyDirective implements OnInit {
  TemplateRef _templateRef;
  ViewContainerRef _viewContainer;

  @Input('myDummyVariable')
  String variable;

  MyDummyDirective(this._templateRef, this._viewContainer);

  void ngOnInit() {
    // WARNING: the property "variable" has no value assigned within the constructor.
    _viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(_templateRef);
    _viewContainer.get(0).setLocal('data', 'MyDummyDirective.data');
    print('MyDummyDirective.variable = ${variable}');
    _viewContainer.get(0).setLocal('var', 'This is ' + variable);
  }
}
```

[lib/app_component.html](https://github.com/denis-beurive/angulardart-playground/blob/master/directive-structural/lib/app_component.html)

```
<div *myDummy="let d=data; variable:'value from the lib/app_component.html'; let v=var">
        <p>This is a dummy directive.</p>
        <ul>
            <li><b>d</b>=<code>{{d.toString()}}</code></li>
            <li><b>data</b>=<code>{{data}}</code> (makes reference to the instance of AppComponent)</li>
            <li><b>v</b>=<code>{{v}}</code></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

[lib/app_component.dart](https://github.com/denis-beurive/angulardart-playground/blob/master/directive-structural/lib/app_component.dart)

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:myapp/src/directive_my_dummy.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
    directives: [MyDummyDirective],
)
class AppComponent {
    List<int> getData() => [100, 200, 300];
    String data = 'AppComponent.data';
}
```

The result:

```
This is a dummy directive.

<ul>
    <li>d=MyDummyDirective.data</li>
    <li>data=AppComponent.data (makes reference to the instance of AppComponent)</li>
    <li>v=This is value from the lib/app_component.html</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:

[As a picture often speaks better than words...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un9zE.gif)